# Resolving multiple services using constructor injection with Windsor in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I have a controller that takes an instance of ICustomerService. The constructor for one of my implementations (ok, the only implementation atm) takes an array of ICustomerExporter instances.

I'm registering all implementations of ICustomerExporter using the following code:

```
_container.Register(AllTypes
    .FromAssembly(typeof(ICustomerExporter).Assembly)
    .BasedOn<ICustomerExporter>().LifestyleSingleton());
```

And my DefaultCustomerService implementation looks like:

```
public DefaultCustomerService(ISession session, ICustomerExporter[] exporters)
{
    this._session = session;
    this._exporters = exporters;
}
```

However, when I try to run the app, I get the following error:

```
PM.Services.Implementation.DefaultCustomerService' is waiting for the following  
dependencies: - Service 'PM.Services.ICustomerExporter[]' which was not registered.
```

Well pretty clearly it IS registered, I can even stop in the debugger and verify in the container's component list that the ExcelCustomerExporter implementation is there. So why am I getting this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer this question for anyone who comes along, when registering multiple services like this, you must do 2 things:

- [Register the ArrayResolver with the kernel prior to registering types](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Resolvers&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
- [Make sure to tell the kernel to use the interface as the service base.](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Registering-components-by-conventions&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're registering for ICustomerExporter, but I don't know that Windsor will assume that an implementation of ICustomerExporter will always satisfy your ICustomerExporter[] dependency.  Have you tried registering a ICustomerExporter[] dependency also?

Comment: Actually, I meant to come back and comment on this earlier, but I forgot. The issue is that Windsor, by default, will not resolve arrays of services. You have to add the ArrayResolver to the kernel first. Once I did that, and told Windsor to use the Interface as the service base, it worked as expected.